# How can I extract the edge points from an image?

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I want to extract the edge points from a text image and use  `ListPlot[points]` to visualize those points:

[image]

I tried to used `ImageCorners[]` and `CornerFilter[]`, but there isn't any good result:

```
img=ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"] // Binarize

HighlightImage[img, CornerFilter[img] // ImageAdjust]
```

[image]

```
HighlightImage[img, ImageCorners[img]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

```
img0 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLroE.png"];
```

**1.** [`ComponentMeasurements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html)

```
Graphics[{Blue, Values @ ComponentMeasurements[Binarize @ img0 , "Contours"]}]
```

[image]

You can get the coordinate data by a simple `ReplaceAll`:

```
data = Join @@ Values[ComponentMeasurements[Binarize@img0, "Contours"]] /. 
   Line[x_] :> x;

Row[ListPlot[data, Joined -> #, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {False, True}, 
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

**2.** [`RemoveBackground`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveBackground.html) + [`EdgeDetect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeDetect.html)

```
HighlightImage[img0, 
 EdgeDetect @ RemoveBackground[img0, {"Background", Black}], "Lighten"]
```

[image]

Comment: I need data set of points, how can I extract it from your code?

Comment: @vito, please see the update.

Answer (score 6):

You could just do this:

```
img = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLroE.png"];
ListPlot@PixelValuePositions[EdgeDetect@img, 1]
```

[image: amazing]

---

Or if you want to use meshing then:

```
img = Binarize@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLroE.png"];
ListPlot@MeshCoordinates@RegionBoundary@ImageMesh@img
```

If you want to go further and break them up into individual point sets for each letter/hole then:

```
gr = MeshConnectivityGraph@ImageMesh@img;
comps = ConnectedGraphComponents@gr;
pts = GraphEmbedding /@ comps;
ListPlot[pts]
```

Note if you do `ListLinePlot` then the order of the points may not come out as expected. You may find it more productive to work with the graphs in `comps`, which have richer information about connectivity, instead of using raw points.

Comment: Note, if you want a better quality mesh you should rasterize the image at a higher resolution first for example: `ImageMesh@Rasterize[img, RasterSize -> 3000]`

Comment: MeshConnectivityGraph doesn't work for me, I have Mathematica 12.0